# vaadin custom layout setting a text area in a table with the location attribute

Tags: html, vaadin, vaadin7

I need to set a text area in the html template and use it as a custom component in vaadin the html snippet is as below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            JUNK SENTENCE
        </td>
        <td>
             <div location="HEADIN"></div>
             <div location="Details"></div>
             <div location="Attachment"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>School of more than 50 students univer versities.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

All the place holders are working and displays data but the "details" holder should be a text area.
 as the text is a lot over there so I tried the below way but it just turned the place holder to text vaadin could not manipulate / identify the "Details" place holder. 
I tried the below way i set -  in side the text area tag.

```
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">

            </textarea>
```

and again i tried this way too which also did not work.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" location="Details">

    </textarea>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated to solve this
I am setting the needed values from a formfeildfactory and these values are set by implementing the Vaadin Custom field class(in case it helps some more to identify)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What are you trying to do with the textarea? Why aren't you simply using a Vaadin TextArea component?

Comment: Hi I am not using the vaadin text component because this is a big form and I have added only a segment hence making the form from vaadin is a bit hard so I used the html component and set it with the vaadin tag to be replaced where needed!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create vaadin textarea and textfields for your form elements.
You have then to place them in the custom layout via the "customLayout.addComponent(component, "locationName") " method

It will remove your  tags as described here:

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.customlayout.html